# Convert two columns into two lists for plotting with Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am a beginner programmer and I am having troubles with the following:

I have a dataset in a python file which I would like to plot. The data looks as follows:

```
0.00000000,0.00000000

1.00000000,2.92610390

2.00000000,2.91658800

3.00000000,2.90708989

4.00000000,2.89760956
```

I would like to plot the first number in each row as x-axis, and the second number in each row as y-axis. How would I go about this? I have tried using pandas and converting it to two lists, but this did not work for me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is well explained in the [pandas tutorial](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html). I suggest spending some time with it. Additional functionality is based on matplotlib, the library used by pandas. They also have [excellent tutorials](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/tutorials/index.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If file has no header you can pass `names` parameter to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) and then use [`DataFrame.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, names = ['x', 'y'])

df.plot(x= 'x', y= 'y')

#thank you Mr. T
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael, thanks for your swift reply! Say my filename is log.csv, how do I input the file name? Would it be something like df = pd.read_csv("log.csv", names ....)?

Comment: @aeengineer - exactly you are right. If data in format like in question it working well

Comment: thanks the code works! I only somehow dont get to see a plot when I run it, do you know why this is?

Comment: @aeengineer - What is your IDE? anaconda spyder?

Comment: I am using atom

Comment: @aeengineer - I never use atom, so no idea, sorry.

Comment: You probably just have to tell matplotlib to display the plot: `plt.show()`.

Comment: Mr. T Thanks a lot, this works, I just read it in the matplotlib guide you linked above as well

Comment: I totally understand this. It drove me up the wall at the beginning that seemingly half of the code on SO did not work because people implicitly assume imports and conventions are clear. Some environments also display graphs automatically.